# How to use the stat command on OS X to display a file or directories creation date / time?

Tags: macos, terminal

How to use the stat command on OS X to display a file or directories creation date / time?

```
stat filename
```

What options to use with the f flag?

Comment: I tried "man stat", and that's why I'm here :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will give you the creation date, output it and convert the time to a more readable sequence :

`stat -f %SB file/directory`

Do note that Mac OS X keeps track of the creation time of a file/directory, whereas Linux doesn't since it isn't required by POSIX. You can find more information [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file)

For more informations about the format you can use for the `stat` command, go check the man page for stat(1) [here](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/stat/).

Comment: For me, doing `stat -f %SB -t %Y file` only prints the creation year. But `stat -f %SB file` prints the creation date and time.

Comment: @mchenja you're right, I edited it, thx. Thought about the year when talking about creation date.

Comment: I wanted to add that you can just print the Unix Timestamp by using `%B` instead of `%SB`. This also works for all files & directories within a single directory by using an asterisk `file/directory/*`